# Problem with ode system, using solve_ivp. ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, math, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve ODE system. It is simulation of vehicle movement which includes P regulator.

At this point I don't know what is exactly wrong.  Error occurs: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. I've tried to do it with ode.integrate but the results is the same.
Also I don't exactly know how to indicate some dependencies like position- velocity or di/dt - i where i is electric current, it's probably the reason.

Some code explanation: velocity is regulated by torque(T_m), which is regulated by electric current (i), which is regulated by voltage (U_m), voltage is equal to difference between current velocity and velocity from V(t) function. V(t) function is giving back interpolated velocity from CSV file.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


def F_t(y,p):
    if y[1]>0.1:
         return p[3]*(1+p[4]*y[1])
    else:
        return 0
    
def T_m(y,p):
    return y[3]*p[11]

def F_n(y,p):
    return T_m(y,p)*p[7]*p[13]/p[6] - F_t(y,p)
    
def U_m(t,y):
    return (V(t) - y[1])*p[10]

def carx(t, y, p):
    s, v, s_c, i = y
    p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16 = p # there is a lot of p's because later there will be more equations
    ds = v
    dv = F_n(y,p)/(p5*p3)
    ds_c = V(t)            # theoretical distance
    di = (U_m(y,p) - i*p8 - v*p12*p7/p6)/p9
    return np.array([ds, dv, ds_c, di])

y0 = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0])
t_span = np.linspace(0, 1801, 18000)
sol = solve_ivp(lambda t, y: carx(t, y, p), [t_span[0], t_span[-1]], y0, t_eval=t_span)
```

There is more code, but i don't think it's necessary to show importing CSV file.
I hope everything is clear. I did working code in Julia, so i can show if someone ask.

Comment: We don't need code explanation, we need debugging information.  Specifically the full error, with traceback.  And of course the code where that error occurs, and if possible info on your variables at that point.

Comment: Double check where the arguments to `solve_ivp` match the documentation.  For example does `carx` return the correct shape/size of values (matching `y0` if I recall the requirements correctly).

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Instead of reading data from a CSV file, you could code a literal array into the example.  Note that you haven't defined `p`, nor the function `V`, which is used in `U_m` and `carx`. Have you verified that `V(t)` returns a scalar?

Comment: Usually this error occurs where the interpolation has to happen by not using interpolation but using the whole value array. Now you said you use interpolation, so the error has to be more interesting. In the presented code there seems to be no place where a variable gets a sequence assigned by accident, so indeed what is needed is either more code, the error message with the code lines it complains about, or you using a debugger on a test function call to `carx(0,y0,p)` with an eye on scalar variables changing into sequences.